# requests GET requests take a long time for a reponse

Tags: python, python-requests

Sending get requests to any site takes a long, varying from 1-2 minutes

I have tried

restarting computer

reinstalling python

restarting vscode

updating pip

updating python

updating vscode

resetting network settings

**Code Used**

```
import requests, time

start = time.time()
url = 'https://google.com'
requests.get(url)

print(f"it took {time.time() - start} seconds to process the request")
```

*it took 168.57493925094606 seconds to process the request*

Comment: Does this only occur with Google? They may well throttle requests made by the requests library. (You can try another URL, or changing the Requests user-agent header.)

Comment: This occurs with every site, along with pip, pip install usually takes the same amount of time

Comment: Do you have a regular web browser installed on the same machine, and if so, does it have the same problem?

Comment: I am using google chrome, This doesn't happen with any web pages, They almost load instantly

Comment: Fixed, Disabled ipv6